# Regular expression for A123ABC

Tags: regex

I have a string in the format `A123ABC`

- First letter cannot contain `<I,O,Q,U,Z>`
- Next 3 digits (0-9) from 21-998
- Last 3 letters cannot include `<I,Q,Z>`

I used the following expression `[A-HJ-NPR-TV-Y]{1}[0-9]{2,3}[A-HJ-PR-Y]{3}`

But I am not able to restrict the number in the range 21-998.

Comment: please give me an example input string

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a bad problem to be approaching using regex; if you split the string up into the three sections (letter, numbers, letters), you could easily validate them separately.

Comment: To restrict numbers use ([0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|21)[^0-9] BTW the ( ) is just to make it more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your letter part is fine, below is just the numbers portion:

```
regex = "(?:2[1-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9][0-9]|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-8])"
```

`(?:...)` group, but do not capture.
`2[1-9]` covers 21-29
`[3-9][0-9]` covers 30-99
`[1-8][0-9][0-9]` covers 100-899
`9[0-8][0-9]` covers 900-989
`99[0-8]` covers 990-998
`|` stands for "or"

Note: `[0-9]` may be replaced by `\d`. So, a more concise representation would be:

```
regex = "(?:2\d|[3-9]\d|[1-8]\d{2}|9[0-8]\d|99[0-8])"
```

Comment: Extra ``[`` at the end

Comment: This won't match 899, which should be allowed.

Comment: @SQB Good call , give me a sec.

Comment: 20 shouldn't be a match. It is in your regex. EDIT : and now you're not matching 30, 40, etc anymore :)

Comment: @Theox Thanks.  It's been a long night.

Comment: This won't match 989, which should be allowed.

Comment: @SteveP. Don't worry, I got it covered `:)`

Comment: @Theox Crap, I'm being a baddie tonghit.

Comment: @SQB Lol, yeah, it devolved into yours.  Not that that's a bad thing. +1 to you.

Comment: \*Makes note to self\* slowchat in comments gets confusing. But yeah, now you've got the same answer as I do, yours works too `:)`

Comment: @SQB Also note to self, do not answer questions on no sleep. :)

Comment: @SteveP. Hi i didn't get the ?: part.Why is it used?I am new to this area.

Comment: @user3069600 You use `(...)` when you want to extract `...`; if you're just trying to match a pattern and there's no need to extract the content, you use `(?:...)`.  For example, if you just want to match a number or a letter, you could use: `(?:\d|[a-zA-Z])`, but if you wanted to extract that number or letter for later use, you would do `(\d|[a-zA-Z])`.  Here's some [additional information](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  In general, the site is really helpful.

Comment: @SteveP. so if i dont use ?:,then also it should work fine right?

Comment: @user3069600 It would work, but there's no reason to extract the strings unless you have to-- it's less efficient.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be matching `(\d+)` and checking if that falls in the range 21 - 998 *outside* a regex, in the language you're using, if possible.

---

If that is not feasible, you have to break it up (just showing the middle part):

```
(2[1-9]|[3-9]\d|[1-8]\d\d|9[0-8]\d|99[0-8])
```

Breakdown:

- `2[1-9]` matches 21 - 29
- `[3-9]\d` matches 30 - 99
- `[1-8]\d\d` matches 100 - 899
- `9[0-8]\d` matches 900 - 989
- `99[0-8]` matches 990 - 998

---

Also, the `{1}` is superfluous and can be omitted, making the complete regex

```
[A-HJ-NPR-TV-Y](2[1-9]|[3-9]\d|[1-8]\d\d|9[0-8]\d|99[0-8])[A-HJ-PR-Y]{3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the numbers between 21 and 99 are displayed with three digits (ie. : 021, 055, 099), here's a solution for the number part :

```
((02[1-9])|(0[3-9][0-9])|([1-8][0-9]{2})|(9([0-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])))
```

Entire regex :

```
[A-HJ-NPR-TV-Y]{1}((02[1-9])|(0[3-9][0-9])|([1-8][0-9]{2})|(9([0-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])))[A-HJ-PR-Y]{3}
```

Comment: Paste the complete string, otherwise it will be unlimited to another digit appearing after the end

Answer (score 2):

There are probably easier ways to do this, but one way would be to use:

```
^((?=[^IOQUZ])([A-Z]))((02[^0])|(0[3-9]\d)|([1-8]\d\d)|(9[0-8]\d)|(99[0-8]))((?=[^IQZ])([A-Z])){3}$
```

**To explain:**

1. `^` denotes the beginning of the string.
2. `((?=[^IOQUZ])([A-Z]))` would give you any capital letter not in <`I`, `O`, `Q`, `U`, `Z`>.
3. `((02[^0])|(0[3-9]\d)|([1-8]\d\d)|(9[0-8]\d)|(99[0-8]))` denotes any number between ((21 to 29) or (30 to 99) or (100 to 899) or (900 to 989) or (990 to 998)).
4. `((?=[^IQZ])([A-Z])){3}` would match any three capital letters not in <`I`, `Q`, `Z`>.
5. `$` would denote the end of the string.

Comment: The first group of your regex will match anything but IOQUZ, ok. Anything including symbols, digits, etc. For example, "*021/" is matched.

Comment: @Theox: Had accidentally submitted mid-way. It should be fine now.